# Why does the JavaScript RegExp /^\w+$/ match undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

Why does the the RegExp `/^\w+$/` match `undefined`?

Example code:

```
alert(/^\w+$/.test(undefined));
```

This will display true in Firefox 3 (only browser I tested it on).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When `undefined` is cast to a string (which the regex does), it produces the string `"undefined"`, which is then matched.

Comment: Perhaps a little... but there's no real concept of exceptions or anything like that in JavaScript, a little quirky behaviour is better than dieing silently.

Comment: Well there are Errors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Error)...

Comment: In my (admittedly, rather limited) experience though, they aren't all that much use in most cases...

Comment: ___Horrible___ language design.

Comment: This becomes a BIG problem in JS when you're testing for the presence of a string of any value. When the string variable is defined but not populated, as in var str; then its value is the undefined property. This gets coerced to a string type by the test() method, and will logically act as though the string actually was defined and set to the string value "undefined". So don't use test() to check for the presence of strings, or if you do, make an explicit check for undefined first.

Answer (score 6):

```
/(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)/.exec(undefined);
```

returns: `["undef", "u", "n", "d", "e", "f"]`

It is treating undefined as the string `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 4):

See ECMAScript Specification section 15.10.6.2 for RegExp.prototype.exec(*string*) which will be called from .match method.  match basically is exec when it's evaluated to true.

Here is word for word from the specification:
Performs a regular expression match of string against the regular expression and returns an Array object containing the results of the match, or null if the string did not match
The string ToString(string) is searched for an occurrence of the regular expression pattern as follows:

1. Let S be the value of ToString(string).
2. Let length be the length of S.
3. Let lastIndex be the value of the lastIndex property.
4. Let i be the value of ToInteger(lastIndex).
5. If the global property is false, let i = 0.
6. If I < 0 or I > length then set lastIndex to 0 and return null.
7. Call [[Match]], giving it the arguments S and i. If [[Match]] returned failure, go to step 8;
   otherwise let r be its State result and go to step 10.
8. Let i = i+1.
9. Go to step 6.
10. Let e be r's endIndex value.

As you can see it will translate any input to a string, so undefined becomes 'undefined' and that will match to true.

Tested this as well outside the browser using JScript in command line and getting the same result.